# ШпаКлевка или шпаТлевка?

Tags: орфография

Я что-то никак не могу для себя уяснить, как правильно: шпаТлевка или шпаКлевка? То так встречаю, то так. Или это два совершенно разных материала?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Что касается употребления слов шпаклёвка и шпатлёвка, то в современных словарях оба варианта выступают как равноправные. Например, в Большом толковом словаре (С-П., 2000): Шпаклёвка 1. к шпаклевать. 2. Пастообразная замазка, которой шпаклюют какую-л. поверхность; слой этой замазки, нанесенный на какую-л. поверхность (с. 1503). "Шпатлёвка = шпаклевка (с. 1504). См. также русский орфографический словарь (ответственный ред. В. В. Лопатин, М., 1999, с. 1199). В вышеупомянутом словаре-справочнике Л. И. Скворцова по поводу исторической последовательности появления слов шпаклевка и шпатлевка написано: «Эти существительные имеют общее значение: «замазка для заполнения неровностей какой-нибудь поверхности» и «процесс нанесения этой замазки» (при подготовке поверхности к покраске). Образованы они от разных глаголов: шпаклёвка – от шпаклевать, а шпатлёвка – от шпатлевать. В XIX веке существовал еще один, ныне совсем забытый вариант этого слова: шпадлёвка (от глагола шпадлевать в том же значении). Все три русских глагола, от которых образованы слова шпаклёвка, шпатлёвка, шпадлёвка, восходят к одному и тому же немецкому глаголу spachteln, звуковой облик которого видоизменился трояким образом в устной русской речи: шпатлевать, шпадлевать (с озвончением т) и шпаклевать (возможно, не без влияния слов пакля, паклевать и т. п.). Если словарь Даля отмечает троякое варьирование глагола, не отдавая особого предпочтения ни одному из них – шпад (т, к) левать, – то академический Словарь 1847 года закрепляет лишь один вариант: слово шпаклевать (существительное шпаклевка). Эта общелитературная норма сохраняется и до нашего времени. На фоне общелитературных слов шпаклевать и шпаклевка их варианты расцениваются как устарелые, архаичные. Правда, они по традиции могут сохраняться в профессиональной речи маляров, ремонтных рабочих. Более того, вариант с т (шпатлевка) поддерживается словом шпатель – инструмент для нанесения шпаклевки, образованным от немецкого Spatel. В старину слово шпатель могло иметь иной звуковой и орфографический облик: шпахтель (который соответствует немецкому Spachtel "шпаклевка")» (там же, с. 248).

[Грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/igra/contests/archive/39_30)

Т. е. в литературной речи лучше употререблять *шпаклёвка*, но допускается и через "т".

Answer (score 4):

Интересная, и забавная тема :) Я не совсем носитель русского языка, но зато немецкого. Поэтому сразу извиняюсь за какие либо орфографические ошибки.

Сегодня впервые прочитал варианты шпатлевать в одном форуме и тут даже шпадлевать, поэтому совсем случайно попал сюда. Оба варианта как-то режут слух, особенно с буквой **д**. На самом же деле даже в Германии люди путают слова шпатель (Spatel), шпахтель (Spachtel) и шпатен (Spaten). И аналогично глаголы шпательн (слышал исключительно редко) и шпахтельн.

Сразу заранее - шпатен, это просто лопата. А вот другие два слова в немецкой речи почти всегда взаимозаменяемы и могут быть использованы как синонимы. Но в некоторых ситуациях в речи могут все же быть восприняты как "необразованностью" собеседника. Оба вида инструмента могут даже выглядеть крайне похожими, просто быть разных размеров, имея при этом разные цели применения.

Вообще существительное "шпатель" это как правило небольшой инструмент, который используется для кулинарии, косметики, техники, а так же для медицинских и научно-лабораторных целях. Но редко в строительной сфере. Вы может знаете этот инструмент под латинским словом спатула или даже шпатула. Спатула - это возможно самое подходящий перевод с немецкого. Вот оригинальная ссылка на Википедию (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatel). Там есть фотографии, по которым очень хорошо видно, что именно я имею в виду. Не смотрите на русский перевод. Там в артикле (или артикуле? :D) описывается как "исключительно" кулинарная лопатка :D Это лишь одно из применений слова шпатель.

Глагол шпательн я сам встречал в речи крайне редко.

Существительное "шпахтель" используется чаще всего в строительной сфере. Но встречается также как описание для любых других маленьких лопаточек/савков, как плоских для нанесения на поверхности, так и углубленных для сбора какой либо субстанции из емкостей. Но как правило это плоские лопатки для нанесения любой жидкой/вязкой массы/смеси на какую либо - как правило ровную - поверхность. Будь это мебель, стена или поверхность автомобиля. Глагол "шпахтельн" (а то есть шпаклевать) это и есть само действие нанесения массы на поверхность, будь это какой либо раствор для укладки кирпичей или замазка для удаления отверстий или неровностей.

Вот ссылка на шпахтель: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spachtel_(Werkzeug). Ну или то, что на русском принято называть шпателем в промысле.

С моей точки зрения, самые подходящие слова вообще должно быть "шпаХТлевка" и аналогично "шпаХТлевать", если уж быть совсем корректным :D :P Не исключаю возможность, что такое слово в русском действительно какое-то время существовало ))) Полагаю, что все вышеуказанные варианты (включая мой), многим носителям того или иного языка или профессионального жаргона могут резать слух.

Что касается меня, то на немецком я всегда говорил и буду говорить Spachtelmasse (любая масса для нанесения) или Mörtel (например цементный раствор) когда имею в виду саму смесь. **Шпахтель** когда говорю об инструменте для строительства, а **шпатель** для других мелких инструментов для иных целей. И **шпахтельн** когда имею в виду действие нанесения смеси на поверхности. А вот на русском использую только **шпаклевка** и аналогично **шпаклевать**. Из всех вариантов, этот самый подходящий и приятный на слух.

Кстати, не редко слышал аналогичные слова на русском: савок или лопатка. И то и другое также применяется на русском в строительном жаргоне (возможно тоже как попало) как шпатель, шпахтель и шпатен в немецком. Поэтому считаю все варианты шпа(К|Т|Д)левки абсолютно уместными ))))

Еще интересные слова из немецкого:

Дуршлаг - вообще должно быть дурхьшлаг. Кстати с ударением на **у** а не на **а**. Сегодня в Германии молодежь наверняка не знает этого слова. Из старшего поколения, только одного человека встретил, который знал и применял это слово вместо слова Sieb.

Шлагбаум - Сегодня это слово тоже известно только старшему поколению, сегодня мы используем для слова шлагбаум **Schranke**. И с ударением на первое **а** в слове шлаг, что переводиться как удар. А баум это дерево. Вообще шлагбаум это из жаргона охотников, что являлось ловушкой для мелких животных/грызунов - по сути дубинка с весом, которая должна "нейтрализовать" добычу (сегодня запрещено). Да, как русские так и немцы всегда имели удивительное и тонкое чувство черного юмора ))

Answer (score 1):

http://www.otvetim.info/stroitelstvo-i-remont/961
В словарях и энциклопедиях они пишутся рядом, одно просто написано, а второе в скобках. Шпаклёвка (шпатлёвка). В словаре Даля имеется даже три слова, одинаково отражающих суть материала и процесса шпаклевания (шпатлевания).

Можно использовать любой из терминов, обозначающих «пастообразный отделочный состав из вяжущего, базового компонента для выравнивания поверхностей». Процесс шпаклевания выполняется особым инструментом. Его называют – шпатель. По названию инструмента строители называют и материал для шпатлевания – шпатлёвка. Люди, далёкие от строительных работ, называют этот материал шпаклёвкой.

Answer (score 1):

Процесс называется шпаТлевкой, поскольку этот глагол образован от слова шпаТель.
А смесь называют шпаКлёвкой.
Если говорить на "высоком уровне", то правильно в речи употреблять слово шпаТлевка, а если "обычным языком", — то шпаКлевка. Но смысл один и тот же.

Comment: А "поскольку" пишется слитно. Даже если говорить "на высоком уровне".

Comment: Если на банке «Шпатлёвка акриловая универсальная» значится, то это — процесс или смесь?

Comment: Речь вообще только о смеси. Процесс называется шпаклеванием. Ну или шпатлеванием.

Answer (score 0):

*Употребление в этом слове буквы **«К»** или буквы **«Т»** абсолютно не меняет его смыслового значения. Это просто дань традициям.

- Например, моряки в слове **«рапорт»**, делают ударение на втором слоге,
     маркетологи, в слове **«маркетинг»**, делают ударение на первом слоге.

Смысл слов не меняется, а произношение, как дань профессиональным традициям. Главное не в том, как произнести это слово, а в том что материал, называемый **шпатлёвкой** **( шпаклёвкой)** помогает делать поверхности ровными и гладкими, такими чтобы было комфортно человеку. И материал хорошо выполняет своё предназначение.*
[link text](http://www.otvetim.info/stroitelstvo-i-remont/961)

Comment: Мне кажется, слово "шпаКлевка" появилось потому, что произносить "шпаТлевка" просто менее удобно.

Comment: fuchoin-kazuki  Все три русских глагола, от которых образованы слова шпаклёвка, шпатлёвка, шпадлёвка, восходят к одному и тому же немецкому глаголу spachteln. Произнесите это слово. Академический Словарь 1847 года закрепляет лишь один вариант: слово шпаклевать (существительное шпаклевка). Эта общелитературная норма сохраняется и до нашего времени.

Answer (score 0):

В моем строительном институте говорили ШПАТЛЕВКА от слова шпатель. Я так говорю тоже. Может проф привычка? Слово ШпаКель мне "режет" слух. И еще сотня слов: гипсокардон, шихвер, лисапет, транвай, калидор, каклета, щикатурка, кухвайка, шихваньер, пинджак...... Не буду продолжать. 
Много зависит от первого учителя, который поселил новое слово нам в мозг. И оно(слово) менять место прописки не сильно торопится.

Comment: «Может проф привычка?» Не режет?